# Are assistance benefits reported as W-2 box 1 income considered earned income?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, earned-income

First off, I recognize that I am not paying any of you to act as a licensed tax professional for me, so I will take your tax advice as just that, advice.

The university I attend has financial-need-based assistance it provides specifically for students with children.  I received some of this assistance last year.  My question is, **does this money count as earned income for the purposes of the Earned Income Tax Credit?**

Possibly relevant information:

- Social security, medicare, and state withholdings 
  were all taken from this assistance money.
- This money is appearing as box 1 (and 3 and 5) income on my W-2.
- To qualify for the assistance money, I have to be a graduate student and making below a certain amount (there is a graduated phase out) and have to have children below the age of 6.
- Once qualified for assistance money, the money is then paid out on a reimbursement basis, reimbursing for child-related housing, medical insurance, and child care expenses up to a certain maximum each month (determined as total assistance amount divided by 12).

Comment: Do you work for the income? Like, do you do work as a teacher or research assistant?

Comment: @stannius, I am paid from a fellowship for my main stipend.

Comment: This seems relevant, even though it doesn't answer your headline question: http://pfforphds.com/grad-student-tax-lie-8-you-can-claim-the-earned-income-tax-credit/  Note that it states that if the income shows up on a W-2, it probably does count.